# Data node shuts automatically with error "WARN datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, datanode

I am recieving below error for data node, even resource manager shuts automatically

2021-05-05 01:13:32,029 WARN common.Storage: Failed to add storage directory

```
[DISK]file:/C:/hadoop/data/datanode
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in C:\hadoop\data\datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-c6716736-36ba-454d-840a-ef8d77ac52c3; datanode clusterID = CID-b5548c69-4ac5-46ab-a413-11436c51ffad
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadStorageDirectory(DataStorage.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadDataStorage(DataStorage.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:816)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-05-05 01:13:32,029 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid c9a3733b-f995-4ed3-8441-b3dd2fd03b7c) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting.
java.io.IOException: All specified directories have failed to load.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:552)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:816)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-05-05 01:13:32,029 WARN datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid c9a3733b-f995-4ed3-8441-b3dd2fd03b7c) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
2021-05-05 01:13:32,129 INFO datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid c9a3733b-f995-4ed3-8441-b3dd2fd03b7c)
2021-05-05 01:13:34,135 WARN datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2021-05-05 01:13:34,150 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
```